# To add new columns that identify the value position by each column with loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have Dataframe:

```
teamId      pts xpts    
Liverpool   82  59
Man City    57  63
Leicester   53  47
Chelsea     48  55
```

And I'm trying to add new columns that identify the team position by each column

I wanna get this:

```
teamId      pts xpts №pts №xpts    
Liverpool   82  59   1    2
Man City    57  63   2    1
Leicester   53  47   3    4
Chelsea     48  53   4    3
```

I tried to do something similar with the following code, but to no avail. The result is a list

```
df = [df.sort_values(by=i, ascending=False).assign(new_col=lambda x: range(1, len(df) + 1)) for i in df.columns]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) with [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and add new DataFrame to original `DataFrame`  by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
c = ['pts','xpts']

df = df.join(df[c].rank(method='dense', ascending=False).astype(int).add_prefix('N'))
print (df)
      teamId  pts  xpts  Npts  Nxpts
0  Liverpool   82    59     1      2
1   Man City   57    63     2      1
2  Leicester   53    47     3      4
3    Chelsea   48    55     4      3
```

Another idea with for loop and `f-string`s for new columns names:

```
c = ['pts','xpts']

for x in c:
    df[f'N{x}'] = df[x].rank(method='dense', ascending=False).astype(int)
print (df)
      teamId  pts  xpts  Npts  Nxpts
0  Liverpool   82    59     1      2
1   Man City   57    63     2      1
2  Leicester   53    47     3      4
3    Chelsea   48    55     4      3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option, similar to rank and join recipe shown by jezrael is to use `np.argsort`, this operates on the dataframe (pandas >= 1.2) and returns a df you can join:

```
df.join(np.argsort(-df[['pts','xpts']], axis=0).add(1).add_prefix('No'))
 
      teamId  pts  xpts  Nopts  Noxpts
0  Liverpool   82    59      1       2
1   Man City   57    63      2       1
2  Leicester   53    47      3       4
3    Chelsea   48    55      4       3
```